Reactions of H2SO4 with organic compounds
I learnt about the reactions of alkenes with $\ce{H2SO4}$ in various conditions. Like when alkene reacts with cold conc. $\ce{H2SO4}$. The first step in this reaction and also the rate determining step (RDS) is the formation of carbocation. But what I don't understand is the attack of $\ce{^-OSO3H}$ as a nucleophile. As we all know that $\ce{^-OSO3H}$ is a weak nucleophile due to being resonance stabilized. Whereas when we react alkenes with conc. $\ce{H2SO4}$ (no temp. conditions mentioned) rearrangement of alkenes take place rather than the attack of $\ce{^-OSO3H}$ as a nucleophile.
Again something similar is observed in the reaction of dehydration of alcohols. Where the RDS is the protonation of alcohol by $\ce{H2SO4}$ leading to the formation of carbocation. But in this reaction $\ce{H2SO4}$ acts as a catalyst and thus $\ce{^-OSO3H}$ extracts a proton from the intermediate to form a stable alkene.
Could someone clear my doubts on when or at what conditions $\ce{^-OSO3H}$ acts as a nucleophile and when it acts as a catalyst?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/142490/what-is-the-significance-of-using-cold-conc-h2s04-followed-by-boiling-water-for ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6821/reaction-of-benzene-with-2-methylpropene
